# Simple-Salesforce API object agnostic

Tags: simple-salesforce

Trying to figure out a way if I can use this API to get retrieve data if I only have the ID (don’t know if it is a task or a contact, etc.)

I think no but just want to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Simple-Salesforce appears to use the REST API, but it doesn't have a method to call the UI-API at this point (you'd have to build a method in for that).

You can use the [User Interface API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) having just an ID:

```
/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/record-ui/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

It will return the layout, values, record type mapping, etc for the record.

Comment: There is a generic `restful()` method available that can be given an arbitrary REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

`simple_salesforce` has a convenience method to obtain the global describe results. You can walk through that data structure to build a dictionary of object key prefix to API name, and use that dictionary to figure out what type of ID you are holding.

Below `sf` is your `simple_salesforce.Salesforce` connection object.

```
key_prefix_map = {}
for sobj in sf.describe()['sobjects']:
    if sobj['keyPrefix'] is not None:
        key_prefix_map[sobj['keyPrefix']] = sobj['name']
```

or we can one-liner it with a dict comprehension:

```
key_prefix_map = { sobj['keyPrefix']: sobj['name'] for sobj in sf.describe()['sobjects'] if sobj['keyPrefix'] is not None }
```

Then you can look up the first three characters of your Id in that dict to get the API name of the sObject to which it belongs, from which you can construct a `simple_salesforce` proxy object:

```
proxy = sf.SFType(key_prefix_map[my_id[:3]])
```

Against that proxy, you can do retrieves, updates, etc., just like you normally would with `simple_salesforce`; it's just like holding a reference to `sf.Contact` or `sf.Account`. So you could do

```
data = proxy.get()
```

to retrieve the record, or do

```
proxy.update(my_id, {'LastName': 'Test', 'FirstName': 'John'})
```

to perform an update. Naturally, you can also template out a Dynamic SOQL query, and you don't need to get the proxy object to do so:

```
sf.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + key_prefix_map[my_id[:3]] + ' WHERE Id = ' + my_id)
```